# UMVUE of $P(X=0)^2=e^{-2\lambda}$ for $X\sim Pois(\lambda)$ with single observation

Tags: estimation, umvue

I found a similar question asked previously, however that question involved a random sample $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ where as this problem only has a single observation, so their method of finding $P(X_1=X_2=0|\sum_i X_i)$ does not seem possible.

If $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and we want the UMVUE of $P(X=0)^2=e^{-2\lambda}$. Clearly $X$ itself is sufficient complete so we simply need to find an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$. ie. solve

$$\sum_x \delta(x) \frac{\lambda^x }{x!}e^{-\lambda}=e^{-2\lambda}$$

or equivalently

$$\sum_x \delta(x)\frac{\lambda^x }{x!} = e^{-\lambda} = \sum_x \frac{(-\lambda)^x }{x!}$$

But this seems to suggest $\delta(x) = (-1)^x$ which is clearly a nonsense estimator.

So I am insure how to proceed.

Comment: It is one of the several cases where an unbiased estimator (also UMVUE here) is absurd. This clearly happens in estimating functions of the form $e^{-k\lambda}$ when a single observation is drawn from  Poisson distribution.

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming, it's very much appreciated.